# Adjust a number of images width to remain inside a parent, aligned horizontal

Tags: css

I have a space where I need, to store for images, each image width being 25% of total width.

Indifferent of the image size, the image needs to adjust to 25% width.

Also there is a padding between images, but the first and last don't have padding to the parent.

I'm using `float` because some users use IE9 and 10.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.row {
  max-width: 35rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lt {
  margin: 3rem auto 0;
}

.lt a:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.lt a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  width: 25%;
}

.lt a img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="lt clearfix">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break down the problem you have **4 elements that take 25% of the parent**, but you also have a **padding of 0.5rem on 3 of them**, and this will result that **the 4 elements will take more the 100% of the container**.

IE9 has partial support for `calc`, so I propose you subtract the padding you give to each element to the width using `calc`, like so:

```
width: calc(25% - (1.5rem / 4));
```

**EDIT:**
As the OP states later, there is `box-sizing:border-box`, to solve this other issue, this answer changes `padding` to `margin`.

See the complete example here:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  max-width: 35rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lt {
  margin: 3rem 0.5rem 0;
}

.lt > a + a {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.lt a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(25% - (1.5rem / 4));
}

.lt a img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="lt clearfix">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Bonus:**

I've changed your strategy to give padding between the images, to use adjacent sibling selector:

```
.lt > a + a {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: I actually use box-sizing:border-box, I forgot to add it, the problem was that the elements in the middle are shorter

Comment: I've edited the answer @user3541631 it should still solve your issue using `margin` instead of `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 & 10 will support `calc` so you can get actual percent sizes. Also I'd try to keep the padding/margins the same on all the images. Then mess with the container to make everything line up.

```css
  .row {
  max-width: 35rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.lt {
  margin: 0.3rem auto 0 auto;
}

.lt a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0 .5rem; /* top/bottom & left/right */
  /* padding-left: 0.5rem;  -- removed it's the same as above */
  width: calc(25% - 1rem); /* max-width minus padding */
}

.lt a img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="lt clearfix">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually use box-sizing:border-box, I forgot to add it, the problem was that the elements in the middle are shorter

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 35rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-right: -1rem;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.box {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.box-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.box-img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="box">
      <a class="box-link" href="#"><img class="box-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="box-link" href="#"><img class="box-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="box-link" href="#"><img class="box-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a class="box-link" href="#"><img class="box-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually use box-sizing:border-box, I forgot to add it, the problem was that the elements in the middle are shorter

Comment: I edited the above to account for `border-box`. This approach is similar to Bootstrap 3 grid which was based on floats and % widths.

Comment: This also looks like the only answer to account for the first and last items not being padded away from the parent box.